# Javascript & object & function

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a function called `hello()`.

Then I retrieve a DOM element with `x = document.getElementById("test");`

How can i make this function behave like `x.hello();`?

Comment: What do you mean "like `x.hello()`"?

Comment: @Jon: Probably `x.hello = function(){hello();}` or another horrid code construct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you need to add a function to an element, you have to modify it's prototype:

```
Element.prototype.hello = function() {
}
```

which will work for any element however you select it.

Say you would like to change the style of the element, it would be something like:

```
Element.prototype.hello = function() {
    this.style.color = 'blue';
}
```

As discussed in the comments below, this isn't necessarily a good idea. Here is a blog post that discusses why: http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/

So, what you can do is create a utilities class that operates on Elements.

What does it look like?

```
var DOM = {};
DOM.hello = function (element, worldParam) {
    element.style.color = worldParam;
}
```

and so on and so forth.

So, for using this, you'd go something like this:

```
DOM.hello(document.getElementById('#test'));
```

Comment: I'll advice you to not modify the prototype of `Element`

Comment: @Nick: Prototyping DOM elements isn't a good idea. It's not supported by IE 8 and below (I don't know about IE9) and because DOM elements are host objects, they aren't required to comply with your modifications.

Comment: add a function to a DOM object, like if I have hello() assign it to x and make it x.hello();

Comment: To _every_ DOM element on the page? Then you should modify prototype.
To _particular_ - use just assignment.

Comment: @Nick: jQuery and all of the other libraries create functions that wrap around DOM elements instead of modifying their prototypes. It's just not a good idea to modify the prototypes of objects that aren't actually implemented in JavaScript.

Comment: @Mutahhir: I haven't dug around in the internals, but `Element` returns `function Element() { [native code] }`.

Comment: @Nick: Take a look at this: http://www.mikedoesweb.com/2012/creating-your-own-javascript-library/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a `hello()` to **every** DOM element on the page, you should modify its prototype:

```
Element.prototype.hello = hello;
```

But I'll not advice you to do so, because your change can affect almost all js code on the page.

If you want to add a `hello()` to this **particular** element, simply assign it:

```
x.hello = hello;
```

`this` in `hello()` will now refer to `x`

Answer (score 1):

```
x = document.getElementById("test");
x.prototype.hello = function() { // your function }
```

Now you can use x.hello().

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9t746/) out.

The link takes you a sample script on jsfiddle.